# Jquery keeps loading in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote the following Jquery which works fine, but it keeps re-loading the page in a loop. I want it to stop once loaded once, but I want it to trigger again if the window is resized. It seems like it should be easy but I cannot seem to figure it out. I tried .one()...Am I missing something obvious?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($(window).width() < 480){
        javascript:__doPostBack('PC8365$lbtnListView','')
    }
    else {
        javascript:__doPostBack('PC8365$lbtnCalView','');
    }
});
```

Comment: which server coding language are you using?

Comment: you need to check `if(! postback)` kind of behavior but solution also depends on backend server coding language like java, c#, php etc.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using asp.net and that __doPostBack('','') triggers an ajax call. I would suspect that it is firing a callback to $(document).ready in either this call or by including jquery more than once on your page.

Although this won't fix the underlying problem, you could wrap it in within a simple run once flag:

```
var run_once_flag = true;

$(document).ready(function(){
   if (run_once_flag) {
     if ($(window).width() < 480){
       alert('hello - width is under 480');
       javascript:__doPostBack('PC8365$lbtnListView','');
     }
     else {
        alert('hello - width is greater than 480');
        javascript:__doPostBack('PC8365$lbtnCalView','');
     }
   }
   run_once_flag = false;
});
```

Comment: Hmmm. That didn't work, not the jquery is not working at all. Any other suggestions?

Comment: comment out the javascript:_doPostBack lines and see if it is still refreshing continuously. The alert should only show once.

Comment: I did test that originally with an alert command and it doesn't loop, but I need to figure out a way to run the script without it looping. Unfortunately, I don't have access to much of the backend since this website is using a CMS. Any other ideas? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use the developer tools within your browser. If you put a breakpoint on the javascript:__doPostBack call and allow it to run once, it'll stop the second time. You can then investigate what is going on. It sounds like the callback is reloading the page probably through setting window.location

Comment: I can't use developer tools or inspect the code as the page keeps refreshing automatically about every 3 seconds thus refreshing the inspector